# Problems with interchanging summatory and integral

Tags: integration, measure-theory, power-series, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to show why, for $x\in (0,1)$, $\int_{0}^{1}(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-x)^{n})dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} (-x)^{n} dx$. I am trying to apply the Dominated convergence theorem, taking the sequence of partial sums, which I call $f_{k}=\sum_{n=0}^{k} (-x)^{n}$, and trying to find a integrable non-negative function $g$ such that $g$ "dominates" $f_{k}$ for all $k$, i.e., $g\geq f_{k}$, $\forall k$. I think $g\equiv 1$ works, but I don't know how to show that $\sum_{n=0}^{k} (-x)^{n}\leq 1$... Someone could help me a little bit? Thanks!

Comment: Fubini's theorem also works here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $x\in(0,1)$ and any $N\in\Bbb N$,$$\sum_{n=0}^N(-x)^n=\frac{1-(-x)^{N+1}}{1+x},$$and therefore$$\left|\sum_{n=0}^N(-x)^n\right|\leqslant\frac2{1+x}\leqslant2.$$So, yes, you can use the dominated convergence theorem.